# Trying to make view template

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a content-type that has an imagefile and a url; I want the url to wrap around the image. So I'm trying to make a viewtemplate based on the information in `Theming information`

based on this description

```
/**
  * This template is used to print a single field in a view. It is not
  * actually used in default Views, as this is registered as a theme
  * function which has better performance. For single overrides, the
  * template is perfectly okay.
  *
  * Variables available:
  * - $view: The view object
  * - $field: The field handler object that can process the input
  * - $row: The raw SQL result that can be used
  * - $output: The processed output that will normally be used.
  *
  * When fetching output from the $row, this construct should be used:
  * $data = $row->{$field->field_alias}
  *
  * The above will guarantee that you'll always get the correct data,
  * regardless of any changes in the aliasing that might happen if
  * the view is modified.
  */
```

I made `views-view-field--my-view--block--field-image.tpl.php` to look like this:

```
$url = $row->{$field->URL}
?>
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank">
  <?php print $output; ?>
</a>
```

But I'm getting `Cannot access empty property` on the `$row->{$field->URL}` line. Can I only access the image field from within the template for the image field? I was looking at `views-view-fields--my-view--block.tpl.php` but not sure how to access things from in there

Comment: When dealing with a filed template I have never been able to retrieve data for any other field besides the one for which I am creating the template. You might want to consider creating a template for the row, or the style of the view. Then you can have access to all fields available to $row. Nevertheless I wanted to say that you can create this functionality without a template. Add a global text field to your view and use the link and image tokens to create the link.

Comment: @Perisdr I thought it should be possible!... could you explain more about how to do that? not sure what links and image tokens are

Comment: I think @Perisdr is correct that it would be easier to do this at the row level vs field, or todo a rewrite also a great idea... :)

Comment: @Damon when you select text rewrite option you will see suggested tokens below it.

Comment: i dont' see a text-rewrite option.. do I need the tokens module for what you're talking about to be an option?

Comment: i also couldn't figure out what elements to use from the row level because I can't print_r the `$fields` variable

Comment: sorry its called `Replacement patterns`

Comment: Where is the replacement patterns - editing a field in a view? Didn't notice anything like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:
    `<pre>`
    `<?php print_r ($row); ?>`
    `</pre>`
This will give you the full tree of the $row

Comment: Good thinking. I isolated it down to: `$row->_field_data[nid][entity]->field_url[und][0][safe_value]);` Is that safe to use as the value of the field?

Comment: try $row['field_url']['und']['0']['safe_value'];

Comment: sorry, missed your edit... thats why its called safe_value :)

Comment: heh yeah.. I was just concerned that the string might not always be the same, though I don't see why it wouldn't

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this in a template file you could do this by using Rewrite Results within the field settings of a view, either by creating your own Global custom text field or editing the settings of the link field or image field. In the rewrite results section you can create a link around the Image as long as the image and the link are both fields within the view.